# problems with QByteArray and QString convertion

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've got a server and a client and they're connected by TCP (QTcpSocket and QTcpServer). data is sent using QByteArray.

```
void Receive::newConnection()
{
    while (server->hasPendingConnections())
        {
        QTcpSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
        connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(readyRead()));
        connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), SLOT(disconnected()));
        QByteArray *buffer = new QByteArray();
        qint32 *s = new qint32(0);
        buffers.insert(socket, buffer);
        sizes.insert(socket, s);
        qDebug()<<buffer;

    }
}
```

last Line prints the text entered in client in server's console. i want to convert buffer to QString. (or i want to send it to qml file). so when i try :

```
QString receivedText = QTextCodec::codecForMib(1015)->toUnicode(buffer);
```

and give me the error :

```
no matching function for call to 'QTextCodec::toUnicode(QByteArray*&)'
         receivedText = QTextCodec::codecForMib(1015)->toUnicode(buffer);
                                                     ^
```

when using fromAscii or fromStringC it says it's not a member of QString.

what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html#toUnicode):

> **QString QTextCodec::toUnicode(const QByteArray &a) const**
>
> Converts a from the encoding of this codec to Unicode, and returns the
>   result in a QString.

From the above, it follows that the reference is needed and not the pointer. In your case you should change it to:

```
 QString receivedText = QTextCodec::codecForMib(1015)->toUnicode(*buffer);
```